# Vue 3 setup reactive fetch with async json

Tags: javascript, vue.js, async-await, vuejs3, vue-composition-api

I've installed Vue 3 and want to populate a reactive object with fetch from a JSON API.

My component looks like below. I don't get any errors but I don't get any results either.

```html
<template>
  <div>
    {{ state.test.total }}
  </div>
</template>

<script>
import { reactive } from "vue";

export default {
  setup() {
    const state = reactive({
      test: null,
    });

    state.test = async () => {
      return await fetch("https://api.npms.io/v2/search?q=vue");
    };

    return {
      state,
    };
  },
};
</script>
```

I expected to get a number on the screen because that's what's in `total` in the JSON file.

### On `state.test`

If I only output `state.test` I get the output below.

> function () { var self = this, args = arguments; return new Promise(function (resolve, reject) { var gen = fn.apply(self, args); function _next(value) { asyncGeneratorStep(gen, resolve, reject, _next, _throw, "next", value); } function _throw(err) { asyncGeneratorStep(gen, resolve, reject, _next, _throw, "throw", err); } _next(undefined); }); }

Any idea how I can get around it?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

When you do:

```
a = async function test() {
}
```

You're assigning a function to your state. But if you you do

```
a = (async function test() {
})();
```

You're still assigning a promise to `a`, rather than a value. If you want to assign a value you need to resolve this promise:

```
funcResult = await a;
```

Your setup function is not a proper place for code that should be executed during lifetime of your component. You can think of setup function as a factory for your component. Thus setup function should always be synchronous (no async keywrord), otherwise vue would not know what it should display while setup is resolving. Luckily you can use hooks in composition API:

```
import { onMounted, reactive } from "vue";

export default {
  setup() {
    const state = reactive({
      test: null,
    });


    onMounted(async () => {
      const response = await fetch("https://api.npms.io/v2/search?q=vue");
      state.test = await response.json();
    });


    return {
      state,
    };
  },
};
```

**EDIT**

Taking into account @boussadjra-brahim answer, you can actually define async setup function, but only in case if you wrap your component with `<Suspense>`. So you can either go with this or that variant.

Comment: That worked after some modifications. You have switched `)};` at the end of onMounted. I forgot to add `.then((response) => response.json());` at the end of my fetch. Thanks so much!

Comment: +1 "You can think of setup function as a factory for your component. Thus setup function should always be synchronous", useful advice.

Comment: @matt What do you guys think of the `async setup()` solution below? Is it good or is it a bad practice?

Comment: @JensTörnell It's unnecessary for this case. The `setup` function doesn't need to wait. You can do something that returns a promise and use `.then()` to populate a reactive variable. For anything more advanced like loading indicators, you can use the `Suspense` component.

Comment: @JensTörnell I've posted an answer.

Comment: When looking a bit more into it, it seems like `async setup()` is the way to go: https://vueschool.io/articles/vuejs-tutorials/suspense-new-feature-in-vue-3/

I still like this answer as well tho.

Comment: There is no reason to wait for a component's `onMounted` to initiate the fetch.

Answer (score 3):

I think it's better not to `wait`.

**Example:**

```
<template>
    <div>
        {{ state }}
    </div>
</template>


<script>
import { ref } from 'vue';

export default {
    setup() {
        const state = ref({});

        fetch('https://api.npms.io/v2/search?q=vue')
            .then(response => response.json())
            .then(data => state.value = data);

        return { state };
    },
};
</script>
```

Comment: This use case accepts the three proposed solutions, for example my solution could be useful if the component is a data display like tables or lists when we could add a loading indicator then show the data, but it will be  bad if the component contains another dependent logic

Comment: @BoussadjraBrahim Yes, I imagine `Suspense` being useful for that. I don't have enough experience with it to know whether the composition functions should be async or not.

Comment: thanks for the link, they should be async and responsible on an unique logic for fetching and showing data in a grid, let's take an example of a data table which could contain a search input, a grid and pagination component, the suspense should only wrap the part that could be loaded async which is the grid.

Answer (score 1):

You should add `async` to setup option and `await` to the fetch function and wrap your child component by `Suspense` component in the parent component :

```html
<template>
    <div>
      {{ state.test.total }}
    </div>
</template>

<script>
import { reactive } from "vue";
export default {
  async setup() {
    const state = reactive({
      test: null,
    });

    try{
      state.test =  await fetch("https://api.npms.io/v2/search?q=vue");
     } catch (err) {
       console.error(err)
   }

    return {
      state,
    };
  },
};
```

in parent :

```html
<template>
  <Suspense>
    <Child/>
  </Suspense>
</template>
```